# MSChart: How to group RangeBar data with text labels instead of indexes?

Tags: c#, .net, data-visualization, mschart

I'm looking to plot data on a RangeBar chart area (System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting) and I'm having issues grouping the data when I have text values for the labels on the vertical axis.

Here's the pertinent code:

```
var connectedTimeRangeSeries = theChart.Series.Add("ConnectedTimeRangeSeries");
var connectedTimeRangesChartArea = theChart.ChartAreas["PerItemConnectedChartArea"];

connectedTimeRangeSeries.ChartArea = connectedTimeRangesChartArea.Name;
connectedTimeRangeSeries.ChartType = SeriesChartType.RangeBar;
connectedTimeRangeSeries.XValueType = ChartValueType.Auto;
connectedTimeRangeSeries.YValueType = ChartValueType.Auto;

for (int i = 0; i < timeRanges.Count; i++)
{
    string theLabel = timeRanges[i].ItemLabel;

    connectedTimeRangeSeries.Points.AddXY(timeRanges[i].ItemId + 1, timeRanges[i].StartConnectionTime, timeRanges[i].StopConnectionTime);
}
```

`timeRanges` is a list with items having these member types (accessed through public properties with corresponding capitalized names):

```
private int itemId;
private string itemLabel;
private DateTime startConnectionTime;
private DateTime stopConnectionTime;
```

When I call `DataSeries.Points.AddXY()` with the X type as an integer (recall X is the vertical axis on the range bar) it does what I want.  The time ranges are grouped according to the index in the bottom graph:

[image: good chart]

However, when I change to try to use a text label to group them, by replacing `AddXY` with this:

```
connectedTimeRangeSeries.Points.AddXY(theLabel, timeRanges[i].StartConnectionTime, timeRanges[i].StopConnectionTime);
```

the data are no longer grouped:

[image]

It's like each one gets its own bin, and I just want them to be combined by label.  (Each index has one and only one label.)

Any ideas?  Thanks!

Comment: How do you do connectedTimeRangeSeries.Points.AddXY(theLabel, timeRanges[i].StartConnectionTime, timeRanges[i].StopConnectionTime); with 2 values, for me it says I can only have 1 value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use AxisLabel property of the DataPoint.
One way to do it would be something like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < timeRanges.Count; i++)
{
    string theLabel = timeRanges[i].ItemLabel;
    int pointIndex = connectedTimeRangeSeries.Points.AddXY(timeRanges[i].ItemId + 1,   timeRanges[i].StartConnectionTime, timeRanges[i].StopConnectionTime);
    connectedTimeRangeSeries.Points[pointIndex].AxisLabel = theLabel;
}
```