# MS Chart Control Range Bar

Tags: f#, mschart

I am trying to somehow replicate the range bar chart [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd456745(v=vs.100).aspx).

[image]

I've found [this reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6444058/mschart-how-to-group-rangebar-data-with-text-labels-instead-of-indexes) but I don't fully grasp the code.

What I have is a series of task (sometimes accomplished in different periods).

```
let d = [("task1", DateTime.Parse("11/01/2014 08:30"), DateTime.Parse("12/01/2014 10:30")); 
         ("task2", DateTime.Parse("15/01/2014 09:30"), DateTime.Parse("16/01/2014 10:30"));
         ("task3", DateTime.Parse("11/01/2014 08:30"), DateTime.Parse("16/01/2014 10:30"))]
let chart = d |> FSharp.Charting.Chart.RangeBar
chart.ShowChart()
```

I am struggling to understand the logic of the API.

---

I have also tried:

```
let chart = new Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Chart(Dock = DockStyle.Fill)
let area = new ChartArea("Main")
chart.ChartAreas.Add(area)
let mainForm = new Form(Visible = true, TopMost = true, Width = 700, Height = 500)
mainForm.Controls.Add(chart)
let seriesColumns = new Series("NameOfTheSerie")
seriesColumns.ChartType <- SeriesChartType.RangeBar

type SupportToChart(serieVals: Series) = 
    member this.addPointXY(lbl, [<ParamArray>] yVals: Object[]) = 
        serieVals.Points.AddXY(lbl, yVals) |> ignore

let supporter = SupportToChart(seriesColumns)
supporter.addPointXY("AAA", DateTime.Parse("11/01/2014 08:30"), DateTime.Parse("12/01/2014 10:30") )
```

which results in

> System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: You can only set 1 Y values for
>   this data point.

Has something changed in the API since then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trick is initializing the Series with

```
let serie = new Series("Range", yValues)
```

where `yValues` defines the max number of "Y-values".

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure that F# Charting is currently powerful enough to be able to reconstruct the above chart. However, one of the problems seems to be that it treats dates as `float` values (for some reason) and incorrectly guesses the ranges. You can at least see the chart if you use:

```
Chart.RangeBar(d)
|> Chart.WithYAxis(Min=41650.0, Max=41660.0)
```

Please submit this as an issue on [GitHub](https://github.com/fsharp/FSharp.Charting/). If you want to dig deeper into how F# Charting works and help us get this fixed, that would be amazing :-)

Comment: I have tried to use `Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Chart()` directly but I hit a few snags. Is there an example? For Instance as seen [link](stackoverflow.com/questions/6444058/mschart-how-to-group-rangebar-data-with-text-labels-instead-of-indexes) I could try to load the data with AddXY, but I am not sure. On top of that, I don't understand how to work around the c# `param` keyword in F# - why wouldn't a Seq (IEnumerable) work?

Comment: I somehow do not understand this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16783196/f-interactive-pass-paramarray-of-functions

Comment: There is a tutorial on using the library directly here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh297118(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: What I like of Chart Controls is the MSDN documentation. For example: "The IntervalOffset property determines the interval offset of an axis. This value is used as the interval offset of an axis' labels and the major tick marks and grid lines associated with the axis" [link] (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.datavisualization.charting.axis.intervaloffset(v=vs.110).aspx)