# Range bar in MS Chart

Tags: c#, winforms, range, mschart, series

I want to generate bars like in [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6444058/mschart-how-to-group-rangebar-data-with-text-labels-instead-of-indexes):
[image]

However, I get this error:

[image]

Here is the code I use:

```
        // AxisY
        chart1.ChartAreas.Add(CA);
        chart1.ChartAreas[1].AxisY.MajorGrid.Enabled = false;
        chart1.ChartAreas[1].AxisY.Interval = 1;

        // AxisX
        chart1.ChartAreas[1].AxisX.ScrollBar.Enabled = true;
        chart1.ChartAreas[1].AxisX.ScaleView.Zoomable = true;
        chart1.ChartAreas[1].AxisX.MajorGrid.Enabled = false;
        chart1.ChartAreas[1].AxisX.LabelStyle.Format = "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss";

        chart1.ChartAreas[1].AxisX.Interval = 0;
        chart1.ChartAreas[1].AxisX.IntervalType = DateTimeIntervalType.Years;

        minDate = new DateTime(2016, 01, 01, 00, 00, 00, 000);
        maxDate = new DateTime(2016, 12, 01, 00, 00, 00, 000); // or DateTime.Now;

        chart1.ChartAreas[1].Axes[0].Enabled = AxisEnabled.False;
        chart1.ChartAreas[1].Axes[1].Enabled = AxisEnabled.False;

        chart1.ChartAreas[1].BackColor = Color.Transparent;
        chart1.ChartAreas[1].Position.Height = 100;
        chart1.ChartAreas[1].Position.Width = 100;
        chart1.ChartAreas[1].InnerPlotPosition.Height = 90;
        chart1.ChartAreas[1].InnerPlotPosition.Width = 80;
        chart1.ChartAreas[1].InnerPlotPosition.X = 10;

        var series2 = new Series
        {
            Name = "S2",
            Color = Color.Black,
            ChartType = SeriesChartType.RangeBar,
            YValueType = ChartValueType.Auto,
            XValueType = ChartValueType.Auto
        };

        var values2 = new DateTime[3];
        values2[0] = minDate.AddMonths(2);
        values2[1] = minDate.AddMonths(4);
        values2[2] = minDate.AddMonths(6);

        series2.Points.AddXY(1, values2[1], values2[2]);

        series2["PointWidth"] = ".25";

        chart1.Series.Add(series2);
```

The bottom axis is a date time. the left axis is fixed and has words as labels. I need to show gap in data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this looks weird at first glance and the error message is not pointing you in the right direction.

The reason is that you try to add points to the series **before** you have added the series to the chart.

`RangeBar` cannot be combined with any other chart type except bar-type charts.

Therefore (?) the chart can't check if the points are actually added in a valid way and instead of saying so it claims that your series accepts only one y-value.

Solution: Simply add the `series2` to the `Chart` **before** adding any `DataPoints` and all is well..

Comment: Sure, there it goes :D